# Building a dashboard with widgets - when adding a new widget the postback causes all existing widgets to reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, dashboard

I made a first attempt at creating a dashboard in a webforms project and it currently has the following features:
User can add/remove/move widgets

**There is one major problem:** Every time the user adds a new widget to the page all of the other widgets have to make calls to the database to reload their data. The moving/removing of widgets is all done on the client, but adding is the problem.

Can someone give me an idea of what technologies I can use to create a modern dashboard that can add a new widget which will need to make a postback to load all of the new widget's data without needing the reload of all of the existing widget's data on the page. I am willing to switch to MVC, Angular.js, knockout.js whatever is necessary. I have found very limited resources on creating a modern dashboard in a web app. Demos, tutporials, examples would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it would be hard to pinpoint what the issue is, but i would suggest wrapping your widgets in an UpdatePanel.

Hope this helps,
Apex